# Should I replace nails in a plywood subfloor with screws to the joists?

Tags: flooring

As you may know I asked a few questions to this end already and just wanted to know if I should remove the nails and replace them with screws to hold the 1/2" plywood sub floor securely to the joists so that I will not get noise in the new floor?

Or is that overkill and adding a screw near each nail is good enough?

Once the flooring goes down I don't get a re-try so I would rather get it right the 1st time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not need to remove the existing nails.  Driving a new screw into the joist adjacent to the nails should be sufficient.

You may need to countersink the screws to get them to sit flush.

Comment: for sure, the screw will sit nice and snug in the plywood !

Comment: +1 and screw size should be chosen properly. If screws are too small they just won't hold the subfloor reliably and it will start squeaking sooner or later.

Comment: @sharptooth what size would be needed for this? i was going to use 2" screws

Comment: @kacalapy: I'm used to millimeters - I'd choose at least 4 mm in diameter and at least 20 mm in length, preferably longer.

Comment: It helps if the screw shank does not have threads on the portion that is in the plywood (1/2" in your case) when the screw is fully seated. This allows the screw to pull the plywood down to the joist.